# Winform - Bug na utilização do Tabcontrol com MetroFramework

Tags: c#, winforms, metroframework

Então, estou tendo um probleminha quando utilizo o Tabcontrol customizado pelo [Modern UI MetroFramework](http://denricdenise.info/2014/09/how-to-use-winforms-modern-ui/).

Acontece que aparece uma barra na lateral superior esquerda (barra de rolagem) e só some se eu der um evento de click em cima dela. Ex:

[image: Edit2: barra destacada]

Já procurei bastante sobre e até agora não encontrei solução nenhuma.

Comment: Tá falando da barra azul?

Comment: @LINQ, olhe a nova imagem. Agora destaquei melhor a barra, que no caso só aparece quando eu exibo o form.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finalmente achei a solução... O que acontece é que deve existir algum erro relacionado ao Size do **MetroTabControl**, então a [solução encontrada](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36934143/6000539) basicamente diz que você tem de preencher a **TabPage** com um **DockStyle.Fill** ou simplesmente jogar um **DockStyle.Left** pra sumir com o erro.